# using external mysql database

Tags: mysql, external

I can only create one database on my current host, which is already made. The problem is that i need another one.

So my question is, is it possible to upload my files to the first host, then signup for another host that has the option to create mysql database, then connect that database to my first host?

Comment: Probably not, why do you need a second distinct database instead of just creating more tables within your first?

Comment: that depends on the hosts.

Comment: It would be a good time to switch for another host

Comment: I'm using opencart on my first database, adding more tables would look really messy

Comment: Looking messy !== the same as not viable.  If that's the restriction you have, it will be far simpler than trying to get 2 essentially seperate databases to communicate when they may not even be on the same physical machine.

Comment: Some framework let you prepend a string to every table names for that very reason. I don't know opencart, but if the feature exists you could use that, which kinda reduce the mess. however, if you plan to run several apps, it's better to get different databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add more tables, but use a table prefix on them to keep them organized and not looking messy. Perhaps your tables might look like opencart_users, opencart_items, otherapplication_users, otherapplication_pages, etc, most CMSs support such a thing right out of the box.

Getting another host with MySQL support, while *possible*, is definitely not the best idea, as you might be sending every MySQL query over a larger network (maybe even the internet) then you should be, which can cause severe performance (and security) issues.